# Got 'nan' when using ctypes in python3 where a float is expected

Tags: python, c, ctypes

This is my bmi.c

```
#include<stdio.h>

float height;
float weight;
int getbmi(float h , float w);

int main(){
    return 0;
}

int getbmi(float h , float w)
{
     //float h , w;
    float res;

    res = w/h;
    res = res/h;
    return res;
 }
```

which i'm compiling like that:

```
gcc -shared -Wl,-soname,adder -o bmi.so -fPIC bmi.c
```

then this is my getbmi.py

```
from ctypes import *

bmi = CDLL('./bmi.so')

h = c_float(1.6002)
w = c_float(75)

getbmi = bmi.getbmi
getbmi.restype = c_float
print(getbmi(h, w))
```

when I run getbmi.py I only got a output: nan

I'm confused

Comment: Have you considered carefully reading the Python code and considering what, precisely, it says? There's one small issue that you're missing here, and I'll give you a hint: Look at function signatures.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You return an `int` with `getbmi()` so your `res` is cast to `int` so `1.6002 / 75 / 75 = 0.00028448`, so the cast produce a `0`. But you tell to python that the return type is `float` so python interpret `int` as `float`.

```
float getbmi(float h, float w);

float getbmi(float h, float w) {
  return w / h / h;
}
```

Comment: I think `(w/h)/h` is correct. As an example `(75÷1.6002)÷1.6002 = 29.2895521543` (which is true BMI of My Friend)

Comment: @PalashBauri `(w / h) / h` => `w / h / h` => `w / h * 1 / h` => `w / (h * h)` => `w / h²`.